# If the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ exists, then $\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If the improper integral exists show:

$\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$

Isn't that just simple definition?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$

because the integral exists i can write:

$\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{0} f(x)dx+\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{0}^{b} f(x)dx$

can i now put them simple together and say a=b=t?

Comment: No, it is not simple definition.  The **converse** may fail.  That is, it may happen that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x)dx$ exists, but $\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{0} f(x)dx$ and $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{0}^{b} f(x)dx$ do not exist.

Comment: Adding to GEdgar’s comment, what you’re looking at is the difference between an improper integral and [Cauchy’s principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: Yes, your claim is correct, but the converse is not. Take $ f(x)=x$. The integral diverges but the limit from $-t$ to $t$ is zero.